# Applying a Theme to a WPF UserControl When Hosted in WinForms

Tags: wpf, winforms, themes

I am hosting a WPF `UserControl` (several, actually) in a WinForms application.

Because of visual differences between the default themes for Win7 (Aero), Win8 (Aero2) and (I assume) Win10, I am trying to specify the lowest common denominator theme (Aero) and tailor my UI from there, thereby hopefully avoiding any OS theme issues.

The problem as I understand it is two fold: 1) there is no `System.Windows.Application` object since it is hosted in a WinForms project, so  I have to create one and 2) I have to specify the theme I want to use.

Point one, [thanks to this *Dr. Wpf* blog post](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/), is simple enough to address with the `EnsureWpfApplicationResources()` method *(strings are split where it helps readability)*:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        EnsureWpfApplicationResources();
        AssignWin7Theme();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new myWinForm());
    }

    static void EnsureWpfApplicationResources()
    {
        if (Wpf.Application.Current == null)
        {
            // create the wpf application object
            new Wpf.Application(); // autoassigns to Wpf.Application.Current
        }
    }

    static void AssignWin7Theme()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(
            "PresentationFramework.Aero;V4.0.0.0;" +
            "31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml",
            UriKind.Relative);

        Wpf.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
            Wpf.Application.LoadComponent(uri) as Wpf.ResourceDictionary);
    }
}
```

The `AssignWin7Theme()`, which I derived from [this](https://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/) blog post by [Eli Arbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276083/eli-arbel), is giving me trouble.  The code runs fine (doesn't throw an exception) but the look of my controls isn't changing on Win8 to match what I see on Win7. I thought it was supposed to pick this setting up automagically; is there an attribute I need to set in the XAML on each control?  What else am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `UriKind.Relative` and not absolute. It's weird that it doesn't throw.

Also note the version. If you're on .NET 4.x, it should be `V4.0.0.0`.

Comment: Updated the version - the UriKind.Relative is a copy/paste error - it did throw and I caught it after this post.  Still not seeing the Win7 Aero template on my Win8/Win10 machines, tho.

Comment: the "consistent experience" is exactly what I'm trying to acheive by doing this.  My app looks different on win7 and win8+ (due to differences in the default themes) so I'm trying to eliminate that.

Comment: Eli, how are you testing it?